# Trying to join 2 tables by comparing strings in lowercase/uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server

hope this makes sense. Just trying to join 2 tables based on the same file path string:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (vdir_physicalPath)
FROM dbo.ASPR_IisVdir --gets all distinct paths for the virtual directories

--now I need to list only the records where the 'path' matches ANY of the rows from the results above;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ASPR_FolderAcl
WHERE UPPER(fullname) = ANY OF the rows above

--notice that the strings are lowercase/uppercase plus vdir_physicalPath has an extra '/'
--I tried to inner join but it didnt list me anything; something like:
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ASPR_FolderAcl acl
INNER JOIN dbo.ASPR_IisVdir vdir
    ON UPPER(acl.fullname) + '/' = UPPER(vdir.vdir_physicalPath) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
        --
        --when comparing should I use something like CHARINDEX(UPPER(fullname), vdir_physicalPath) > 0
```

[image]

[image]

thanks
Max

Comment: With as many points as you have you should know we need some kind of details. Sample data, table structure. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You need to give some sample data. It's impossible to tell why your join didn't work without it. Show expected results based off sample data and it'll make it a lot easier on us.

Comment: all the info has been added. thank you

Comment: Change `UPPER(acl.fullname) + '/'` to `UPPER(acl.fullname) + '\'`. Also, consider avoiding the `UPPER` call altogether.

Comment: oh man yeah it was the '/' - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use a case insensitive collation such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` instead of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`? AFAIK, this would also save you whatever slight performance penalty that you're paying by calling `UPPER` AND allow any indexes on the table to still be used.

For more details please read [Collation and Unicode Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx).

If you switch the collation and still have a problem then, based on information provided so far, there's probably something wrong with you logic or you might have gremlins (such as a zero-width space) in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` and in your sample you are using slash `/` instead use backslash `\`